# Getting the number of objects failed to construct

Tags: java, object, exception, constructor

For one of my class assignments, I needed to create a class that creates triangle objects. According to geometric rules, for a valid triangle, the length of any given side should be less than the combined length of other two. The object constructor class that I have written can take any double, which means it is possible to input one side of triangle that is longer than the combined length of other two. This violates the geometric rule for triangles (this is OK). However, I want to keep track of how many triangles violated the geometric rule, thus failing to construct.

Normally, you would use a try, catch block to catch the exception. However, the problem that I have here is that once an exception is reach, the object following the exception are skipped and not created. This causes two problems: first, any legal objects following the illegal one is not create. Second, I can not keep track of how many objects failed to create other than the first illegal one (since the rest is skipped). How can I restructure my code so that I can create legal object even hitting an illegal one and keep count of how many legal / illegal ones?
I have used a custom exception handler object that I've written for triangle objects but I have not included here for reduction of code.
I am a beginner so the solution that might be obvious to you is obscure for me. Your help is appreciated.

Here is my Triangle tester code:

```
public class TestTriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalTriangleException {
        // Start of try block for creating 4 triangle objects
        try {
            
            Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle();            // create first triangle using default constructor
            System.out.println(triangle1.toString());       // output the information about length of sides
            // output info about perimeter and area of triangle
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle1 is " + triangle1.getPerimeter()); 
            System.out.println("The area of the triangle1 is " + triangle1.getArea());           
            System.out.println();
            
            Triangle triangle2 = new Triangle(3, 4, 5);     // create a second triangle given sides
            System.out.println(triangle2.toString());
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle2 is " + triangle2.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("The area of the triangle2 is " + triangle2.getArea());
            System.out.println();
            
            Triangle triangle3 = new Triangle(4, 2, 5);     // create a third triangle given sides
            System.out.println(triangle3.toString());
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle3 is " + triangle3.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("The area of the triangle3 is " + triangle3.getArea());
            System.out.println();
            
            Triangle triangle4 = new Triangle(2, 3, 7);     // try to create an illegal triangle
            System.out.println(triangle4.toString());
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle4 is " + triangle4.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("The area of the triangle4 is " + triangle4.getArea());
            System.out.println();
            
            Triangle triangle5 = new Triangle(2, 4, 9);     // try to create an illegal triangle
            System.out.println(triangle5.toString());
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle5 is " + triangle5.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("The area of the triangle5 is " + triangle5.getArea());
            System.out.println();
            
        // catch exceptions, if any 
        } catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Triangle.getNumberOfObjects() + " triangles constructed");
        System.out.println(Triangle.illegalAttempts() + " triangle(s) failed to construct");        
    }
}
```

and here is class constructor if you need to look into it:

```
public class Triangle {
    
    // declare variables for each side of the triangle
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;
    
    // declare variables to keep track of number of objects created or illegal attempts
    private static int numberOfObjects = 0;
    private static int illegalAttempts = 0;
    
    // default constructor for triangle
    public Triangle() {
        side1 = 1.0;
        side2 = 1.0;
        side3 = 1.0;
        numberOfObjects++;
    }
    
    // constructor for creating triangles based on length of sides
    public Triangle(double newSide1, double newSide2, double newSide3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
        setSides (newSide1, newSide2, newSide3);
    
        numberOfObjects++;
    }
    
    // setter for creating triangles given the length of sides
    public void setSides (double newSide1, double newSide2, double newSide3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
        // According to geometric rules, in triangles, any one side should be shorter than the combined length of other two. 
        // Check to see if any one side is longer than the combined length of other two. If so, throw the designed exception.
         
        if (newSide1 >= newSide2 + newSide3) { 
            illegalAttempts++;
            throw new IllegalTriangleException(newSide1, newSide2, newSide3);
            
        } else if (newSide2 >= newSide1 + newSide3) {
            illegalAttempts++;
            throw new IllegalTriangleException(newSide2, newSide1, newSide3);
            
        } else if (newSide3 >= newSide1 + newSide2) {
            illegalAttempts++;
            throw new IllegalTriangleException(newSide3, newSide1, newSide2);
        } else {
            
            side1 = newSide1;       // In case the geometric rule is not violated, create the sides. 
            side2 = newSide2;
            side3 = newSide3;
        }       
    }
    // constructor for getting the number triangle created
    public static int getNumberOfObjects() {
        return numberOfObjects;
    }
    
    public static int illegalAttempts() {
        return illegalAttempts;
    }
    // constructor for calculating the perimeter of triangles 
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return side1 + side2 + side3;
    }
    // constructor for calculating the area of a triangle given three sides: sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c))
    public double getArea() {
        double perimeter = side1 + side2 + side3;
        return Math.sqrt(perimeter * (perimeter - side1) * (perimeter - side2) * (perimeter - side3));
    }
    
    // create an string object giving information about the triangle
    public String toString() {
         return "Triangle: Side a = " + side1 + ", Side b = " + side2
                 + ", Side c = " + side3;
    }

}
```

The output of the code should be something like this:

> Triangle: Side a = 4.0, Side b = 2.0, Side c = 5.0
> The perimeter of the triangle3 is 11.0
> The area of the triangle3 is 64.48255578061404

> Exception: IllegalTriangleException: Illegal triangle, the sum of any two sides is less than the other side
> Side 1 is 7.0
> Side 2 is 2.0
> Side 3 is 3.0

> 3 triangles constructed
> 2 triangle(s) failed to construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the triangle initializations are identical aside from their values, one option may be to extract your hard-coded values out of the try block. In the case that any one Triangle fails to construct it will be caught, handled, then move on to the next triangle parameter set.

```
public class TestTriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalTriangleException {
        Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle();            // create first triangle using default constructor
        System.out.println(triangle1.toString());       // output the information about length of sides
        // output info about perimeter and area of triangle
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle1 is " + triangle1.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("The area of the triangle1 is " + triangle1.getArea());
        System.out.println();

        List<List<Integer>> triangleEdgeLengths = new ArrayList<>();
        triangleEdgeLengths.add(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5));
        triangleEdgeLengths.add(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 5));
        triangleEdgeLengths.add(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 7));
        triangleEdgeLengths.add(Arrays.asList(2, 4, 9));

        triangleEdgeLengths.forEach((edgeLengths) -> {
            try {
                Triangle triangle = new Triangle(edgeLengths.get(0), edgeLengths.get(1), edgeLengths.get(2));
                System.out.println(triangle.toString());
                System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle is " + triangle.getPerimeter());
                System.out.println("The area of the triangle is " + triangle.getArea());
                System.out.println();
                // catch exceptions, if any
            } catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
            }
        });

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Triangle.getNumberOfObjects() + " triangles constructed");
        System.out.println(Triangle.illegalAttempts() + " triangle(s) failed to construct");
    }
}
```

output

```
Triangle: Side a = 1.0, Side b = 1.0, Side c = 1.0
The perimeter of the triangle1 is 3.0
The area of the triangle1 is 4.898979485566356

Triangle: Side a = 3.0, Side b = 4.0, Side c = 5.0
The perimeter of the triangle is 12.0
The area of the triangle is 77.76888838089432

Triangle: Side a = 4.0, Side b = 2.0, Side c = 5.0
The perimeter of the triangle is 11.0
The area of the triangle is 64.48255578061404

Exception: IllegalTriangleException
Exception: IllegalTriangleException

3 triangles constructed
2 triangle(s) failed to construct

Process finished with exit code 0
```

twicelost requested an option that avoided using Lists. One option that is a little verbose could be to wrap each triangle construction in a try/catch.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalTriangleException {
        Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle();            // create first triangle using default constructor
        System.out.println(triangle1.toString());       // output the information about length of sides
        // output info about perimeter and area of triangle
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle1 is " + triangle1.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("The area of the triangle1 is " + triangle1.getArea());
        System.out.println();

        try {
            Triangle triangle2 = new Triangle(3, 4, 5);     // create a second triangle given sides
            System.out.println(triangle2.toString());
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle2 is " + triangle2.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("The area of the triangle2 is " + triangle2.getArea());
            System.out.println();
        } catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }

        try {
            Triangle triangle3 = new Triangle(4, 2, 5);     // create a third triangle given sides
            System.out.println(triangle3.toString());
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle3 is " + triangle3.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("The area of the triangle3 is " + triangle3.getArea());
            System.out.println();
        } catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }

        try {
            Triangle triangle4 = new Triangle(2, 3, 7);     // try to create an illegal triangle
            System.out.println(triangle4.toString());
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle4 is " + triangle4.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("The area of the triangle4 is " + triangle4.getArea());
            System.out.println();
        } catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }

        try {
            Triangle triangle5 = new Triangle(2, 4, 9);     // try to create an illegal triangle
            System.out.println(triangle5.toString());
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle5 is " + triangle5.getPerimeter());
            System.out.println("The area of the triangle5 is " + triangle5.getArea());
            System.out.println();
        } catch (IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Triangle.getNumberOfObjects() + " triangles constructed");
        System.out.println(Triangle.illegalAttempts() + " triangle(s) failed to construct");
    }
```

Comment: This fixes the problem in my code and I accept the answer. Thanks. However, we still haven't leant about list of list and arrays. I was wondering if I could get the same effect in a simpler way. Any further clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. In that case another option that may match your criteria is copy pasting your try/catch block around each triangle construction. I've updated my answer to include that option.